# Django login required error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: python, django

My django application worked fine before using LoginRequiredMiddleware, after I used LoginRequiredMiddleware i have got this error.

```
This page isn’t working 
127.0.0.1 redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'login_required.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware',
# 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

REPORT_BUILDER_ASYNC_REPORT = True
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mymachine.wsgi.application'
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'index'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'login'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
```

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('login/', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
path('', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
]
```

view.py

```
class LoginView(CreateView):
"""
Login
"""
template_name = "registration/login.html"
defaults = dict()

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(LoginView, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def on_create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, self.template_name, self.defaults)

def init_component(self, request):
    logout(request)
    self.defaults['name_space'] = reverse('auth')
    self.defaults['form'] = LoginForm

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.init_component(request)
    return self.on_create(request, *args, **kwargs)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            login(request, user)
            request.session["company_id"] = 1
            return redirect(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
        elif user is None:
            context = {'name_space': reverse('auth'), 'form': LoginForm,
                       'message': _("username or password is incorrect"), 'add': 'try Again'}
            return render(request, 'registration/login.html', context)
```

This is the url that appears in chrome.

> http://127.0.0.1:4050/login/?next=/login/

I have tried must of the answers in the web but none is worked, please help to solve this, Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Middleware works for every request/response, since you added `LoginRequiredMiddleware` which will redirect to login page but you are not authenticated so again you will be redirected to login page.
This url `http://127.0.0.1:4050/login/?next=/login/` itself explains what is going on here. You are accessing login page but you are redirected to login page again.

I think you are using this repo [django-login-required-middleware](https://github.com/CleitonDeLima/django-login-required-middleware), it is clearly mentioned that on their ReadMe

> To ignore authentication in a view uses decorato @login_not_required
> for FBV or LoginNotRequiredMixin for CBV:

You need to change your `LoginView` to:

```
from login_required import LoginNotRequiredMixin
class LoginView(LoginNotRequiredMixin, CreateView):
"""
Login
"""
... // Rest of the code
```

You can also add list of url where `LoginRequired` should be ignored

```py
LOGIN_REQUIRED_IGNORE_PATHS = [
    r'/accounts/logout/$'
    r'/accounts/signup/$',
    r'/admin/$',
    r'/admin/login/$',
    r'/about/$'
]
```

or  Add `LOGIN_REQUIRED_IGNORE_VIEW_NAMES` setting. Any requests which match these url name will be ignored. This setting should be a list filled with url names.

```py
LOGIN_REQUIRED_IGNORE_VIEW_NAMES = [
    'home',
    'login',
    'admin:index',
    'admin:login',
    'namespace:url_name',
]
```

Comment: Yes I got it and your solution works for me, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like for some reason you use the package [django-login-required-middleware](https://pypi.org/project/django-login-required-middleware/) which provides a middleware so that login is required for all views. What is happening is that the middleware is assuming that even your login view requires the user to be logged in.

You can stop this by using the `LoginNotRequiredMixin` (or `login_not_required` decorator for function based views) provided by the package (Reference [django-login-required-middleware [GitHub]](https://github.com/CleitonDeLima/django-login-required-middleware)):

```py
from login_required import LoginNotRequiredMixin


class LoginView(LoginNotRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    # Your code here
```

Although this solves the issue do you even need to use this package? I would assume the [The login_required decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) and the [The LoginRequired mixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin) should normally be enough to assure users are logged in for views that need it to be that way.